# navigation controller iphone & didload function?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I made a shared class which all classes in the program can see it, and if I change any variable in this shared class and all classes can see this change. I use a navigation controller to navigate between view controllers, and I put some code in `viewDidLoad` function, but when I navigate to the view controller this code called only once.  What should I do to make this code run every time I navigate to this view controller?

Comment: Tuyen has the right answer. I would suggest getting some books about Cocoa Touch programming, they might benefit you quite a bit. If not that, then perhaps read the docs a little more carefully. Just a quick Google search should have solved this.

Answer (score 7):

You can put code in **viewWillAppear** or **viewDidAppear**

These are events that you can use:
– viewWillAppear:
– viewDidAppear:
– viewWillDisappear:
– viewDidDisappear:
– viewWillLayoutSubviews
– viewDidLayoutSubviews

Comment: nothing in the ViewController called ViewWillAppear or ViewDidAppear should i conform something or just write then and implement them ?

Comment: I've updated the answer, you can visit http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html for more information.

Comment: @mohamed. No, there is a viewWillAppear, however I think you are writing in the wrong class. Are you adding this code to your App Delegate class? If so, don't. You should have a separate class for your viewControllers. If you created a completely blank file for your new class, then yes, add a viewWillAppear method.

Comment: @TuyenNguyen a lot of thanks :) i tried your answer and its very useful and it help me to solve the problem :)

Comment: @mohamed It's nothing to annoy you but i want you to look at http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty once.